# Prevent on('click') from being called twice

Tags: jquery

```
function foo() {
  bar.on('click', function (evt) {
    console.log("click");
  }
}
```

If foo is called multiple times, the click handler is added multiple times resulting in the wrong behavior.

How do you stop this?

Comment: Easy, you never put event handlers inside functions that are called multiple times.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for the pretentious answer.  Sometimes it is required.

Comment: No, it's really not, bind the events outside the function, and use jQuery's data or something similar to know when the event handler should fire.

Comment: And if the events are bound to external objects from an API?

Comment: And for clearity, do you want the event handler to only fire on one single click, or just be bound once, but fire on all clicks.

Comment: Seems from the answers, it's unclear, as I would think `one()` wouldn't work at all for this ?

Comment: You'd still be turning the objects from the API into elements somewhere, so you can just bind to the elements once there, or even use delegation.

Comment: My logic seems to be backwards.  I'll take another approach.  Thanks.

Comment: So what you really wanted, wasn't to bind the event handler once, it was to only be able to click the element once, and not again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.one()` to only call once:

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   at most once per element per event type.

```
function foo() {
  bar.one('click', function (evt) {
    console.log("click");
  }
}
```

[JQuery - .one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this like following.

```
function foo() {
  bar.off('click');

  bar.on('click', function (evt) {
    console.log("click");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the handler to exist for a single click, use `$.fn.one`:

```
bar.one( "click", handler );
```

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

> The .one() method is identical to  .on(), except that the handler is unbound after its first invocation.

This being said, I would encourage you to consider whether or not you ought to be binding a handler inside a method that is called multiple times. This may in fact be a bigger issue you need to address.